# SSH Key prompts password for "ssh -Tv git@gitlab.tubit.tu-berlin.de"

Tags: ssh, gitlab

I am trying to connect to GitLab over SSH with ED25519 and followed this source: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/ . When I test the connection and expect the welcome message, instead it does not work and still prompts for a password. I tried my user password, but it doesn't work and I am not sure which password is required at this point. Here's the output.

```
ssh -Tv git@gitlab.tubit.tu-berlin.de

OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
    debug1: Connecting to gitlab.tubit.tu-berlin.de [130.149.7.193] port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: identity file /home/christian/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/christian/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/christian/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/christian/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/christian/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/christian/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/christian/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/christian/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/christian/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
    debug1: identity file /home/christian/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/christian/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/christian/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/christian/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/christian/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
    debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000002
    debug1: Authenticating to gitlab.tubit.tu-berlin.de:22 as 'git'
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
    debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
    debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
    debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<3072<8192) sent
    debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
    debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
    debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:aA86J3auCo20sHneGIvwxk/uay4ynBNkWIgiio/qUUw
    debug1: Host 'gitlab.tubit.tu-berlin.de' is known and matches the RSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in /home/christian/.ssh/known_hosts:3
    debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/christian/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:rFB2QOkPTiiqlMAN1V9RS9QVV2vrgxgRAa9wXm0RdJI agent
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/christian/.ssh/id_rsa 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/christian/.ssh/id_dsa 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/christian/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/christian/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/christian/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/christian/.ssh/id_xmss 
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Offering public key: /home/christian/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:rFB2QOkPTiiqlMAN1V9RS9QVV2vrgxgRAa9wXm0RdJI agent
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/christian/.ssh/id_rsa
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/christian/.ssh/id_dsa
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/christian/.ssh/id_ecdsa
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/christian/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/christian/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/christian/.ssh/id_xmss
    debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
    Password: 
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
    Password: 
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
    Password: 
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
    debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
    git@gitlab.tubit.tu-berlin.de: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

Answer (score 0):

From the guide you mention, you need to double-check:

- you have an OpenSSH 6.5 or newer
- you have copied the public key to your GitLab User account Settings/SSH Keys

I would test it first with a private SSH key without any passsphrase.